# Powershell - Create array from string - separating blocks of text by new lines

Tags: powershell, newline, text-parsing, paragraph

I have a string in a variable:

```
$Test = @"
Paragraph 1: some paragraph text
some paragraph text some paragraph text
some paragraph text some paragraph text

Paragraph 2: some paragraph text
some paragraph text some paragraph text
some paragraph text some paragraph text

Paragraph 3: some paragraph text
some paragraph text some paragraph text
some paragraph text some paragraph text
"@
```

There might be an undetermined number of paragraphs.

The paragraphs are always separated by a new line.

I need each paragraph block of text separated into a new array variable.

Example:

$Array[1] should give me the entire block of text of Paragraph 2.

Thank you!

Comment: `-split (?m)^\r?\n` could work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split by two or more consecutive newlines:

```sh
# Pipe to 
#  | ForEach-Object { "[$_]" } 
# to visualize the resulting array elements.
$test -split '(?:\r?\n){2,}'
```

For an explanation of the regex passed to the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operator and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/CV8wQL/1).

Note:

- If you can assume that only Unix-format LF (`\n`) newlines are present in your input string, you can simplify the regex to `'\n{2,}'` - the regex above handles both LF and Windows CRLF (`\r\n`) newlines.
- If the last paragraph happens to contain a single trailing newline (as would typically happen if you read a text file in full with `Get-Content -Raw`) that you want to eliminate from the array, use:

  ```sh
  # Note: If you need to preserve trailing *non-newline* whitespace,
  #       use .TrimEnd("`r", "`n") instead.
  ($test -split '(?:\r?\n){2,}').TrimEnd()
  ```